# How can I avoid invalid warning C6011 due to an abort function calling exit()

Tags: c

I am trying to avoid C6011 warning because an abort function is calling exit(). How can I do that?

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void abort_function();
void func( int *p );

int main()
{
    int x;

    func( &x );

    return 0;
}

void func( int *p )
{
    if (NULL == p)
        abort_function();

    *p = 5;
}

void abort_function()
{
    exit(0);
}
```

So this leads to the following warning from PREFast:

```
warning C6011: Dereferencing NULL pointer 'p': Lines: 17, 18, 20
```

Simply replacing `abort_function()` with `exit(0)` eliminates this warning.

But I'm actually working with a large codebase, and I didn't want to replace all calls to `abort_function()`. So I was able to eliminate a lot of these warnings by making the function a variadic macro, and temporarily taking out the function definition, like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define abort_function( ... ) exit(0);

/*void abort_function();*/
void func( int *p );

int main()
{
    int x;

    func( &x );

    return 0;
}

void func( int *p )
{
    if (NULL == p)
        abort_function();

    *p = 5;
}

#if 0
void abort_function()
{
    exit(0);
}
#endif
```

This also eliminated the warning, but are there any PREFast options or annotations I could use, to avoid having to modify the code?

Comment: IMHO there is nothing wrong with it (, not even when compiled as C++). Unrelated: `int main()` should be `int main(void)`, BTW.

Comment: Putting the dereferencing under an `else` clause will probably also take care of it, although obviously this won't meet the "avoid having to modify the code" criteria, and if `func()` has more in it than that single dereference, it's going to increase the nesting level for everything which could get annoying in a large function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In MSVC, defining [`__declspec(noreturn)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/noreturn) for `abort_function` should do it.
For gcc, `__attribute__ ((noreturn))` does the same.

Comment: Or since C++11, the standardized [`[[noreturn]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes).

Answer (score 1):

In C, you can eliminate warnings like this using #pragma. Use it carefully, because you want some warnings. Here is the #pragma for eliminating this warning:

```
#pragma warning(disable:6011)
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the right answer, for those wondering! And it works for when you're implementing something other than `exit()`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this warning is because the compiler doesn't realize that abort_function() will never return. Therefore it believes that there is a legitimate code path where p is NULL; abort_function() is called and returns and then you dereference p.

You can avoid it by either using the (noreturn) declaration or modifying your abort_function() invocation to include a return;

```
if (p == NULL)
{
    abort_function();
    return;
}
```